# Why does a move constructed object preserves the capacity of an empty private vector, while a copy constructed object does not?

Tags: c++

### Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Dummy {
public:
    Dummy(int size=5) {array.reserve(size);};
    size_t capacity(){return array.capacity();};
private:
    std::vector<unsigned long long> array;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    Dummy test1(10);
    Dummy test2(10);
    std::cout << "Initial capacity test1: " << test1.capacity() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Initial capacity test2: " << test2.capacity() << std::endl;
    Dummy foo(test1);
    std::cout << "After copy capacity: " << foo.capacity() << std::endl;
    Dummy bar(std::move(test2));
    std::cout << "After move capacity: " << bar.capacity() << std::endl;
}
```

The above is build with g++ 7.4.0 and returns the following:

*Initial capacity test1: 10*

*Initial capacity test2: 10*

*After copy capacity: 0*

*After move capacity: 10*

### Question

Why does the move constructed object preserves the capacity of the empty private vector, while a copy constructed object does not?

Comment: Moving a `std::vector` "steals" the internal memory buffer of the original, so it is no surprise that it doesn't change size.

Comment: The `Dummy` class is not needed for this example - you can do the same thing with plain `vector`s and observe it too. The whole point of moving is to avoid recreating resources (which the copy operation has to do) in the case that the "old" object no longer needs them.

Comment: @molbdnilo I don't think that argument really holds, as copy-construction could be described the same way, yet that *does* change the capacity. Capacity is not considered part of the "value" of a `vector` - it is not a **salient attribute**.

Answer (score 1):

Because copy is copy.

When you copy vector, it copies it's **elements** that it **has**. Not the empty space, that you've planned for your future elements. While move is made to be as fast as possible, as a result it blindly moves everything. Personally i wouldn't plan my code on this. You should rely on move moving reserved space and you shouldn't rely on move leaving after itself an empty container either.

Comment: `Because copy is copy.` well if it would copy everything (the values of the vector and its properties/meta information), then it would also need to ensure that the capacity is the same. But the standard does not require the capacity to stay the same after copying nor does it forbid it, so a copy could maintain the capacity, but is not required to.

Comment: Not neccesary. This is more philosophical question. Is vector's capacity property of value, or more property of variable, that is holding the value? In first case it should be copied, because you want new value to be identical to old one. In second case it should not be copied, because new value is held in different variable. As far as i know standard doesn't say anything about it.